# Why does angular ng-bind not read \n line breaks from JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, line-breaks

I have text from a JSON that looks something like this:

```
"some text some text some text \n\n New paragraph text \n\n Another new paragraph"
```

I then have a simple div that looks like this:

```
<div ng-bind="textFromJSON"></div>
```

For some reason, the text that is rendered to the page turns out without the line breaks. ie

```
some text some text some text New paragraph text Another new paragraph
```

If I look inspect that text with the chrome dev tools, it shows the blocks of text split up into paragraphs using the \n line breaks like I had anticipated.

```
some text some text some text

New paragraph text

Another new paragraph
```

Does anyone know how I can get the page to render it properly?

Answer (score 17):

It does. The issue is html doesn't display it because of the white-space default setting, change your div to this:

```
<div ng-bind="textFromJSON" style="white-space:pre-wrap"></div>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/xtqe7on2/ as an example

Comment: I spent a long time looking at how I was encoding my strings but when in Angular (2+) binding to a string, it was ignoring my JSON linebreaks.  Now they are resolved! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<pre>`

```
    <div><pre>{{textFromJSON}}</pre></div>
```